# Как получить все группы с открытыми стенами по ключевому запросу?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно получить все группы вконтакте с открытыми стенами по данному ключевому слову, например, "подарки".
Как это можно сделать с помощью get запроса и возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Что за ключевое слово? Строка поиска?

Comment: хотите своего спам-бота сделать?

Comment: ключевое слово, допустим "подарки"

Comment: Не хочу спам-бота делать, попросил знакомый, возможно ему для спама надо

Comment: Не дружите с плохими ребятами.

Answer (score 3):

У ВКонтакте API есть метод [`execute()`](https://vk.com/dev/execute?params[code]=return%20API.groups.getById%28%7B%22group_ids%22%3A%20API.groups.search%28%7B%22q%22%3A%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%22%2C%22count%22%3A2%7D%29.items%40.id%2C%20%22fields%22%3A%22can_post%22%7D%29%3B&params[v]=5.48), позволяющий объединять несколько вызовов к API в один.

Примерно такой код сначала находит группы по ключевому слову, а затем получает [их свойство](https://vk.com/dev/fields_groups) `can_post`, означающее, может ли пользователь, от имени которого этот весь запрос выполняется, постить на стену этой группы.

```
return API.groups.getById({
  "group_ids": API.groups.search({
    "q": "подарки",
    "count": 2
  }).items@.id,
  "fields": "can_post"
});
```

Поиск [`groups.search()`](https://vk.com/dev/groups.search) возвращает до 1000 результатов. Один запрос к [`groups.getById()`](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getById) принимает не более 500 групп. Поэтому поиск надо тоже ограничить 500 результатами через параметр `count`.

Comment: А возожно ли обходить ограничение по выводу только 1000 групп на запрос? Ведь по одному ключу может быть гораздо больше, чем 1000 групп

Comment: Конечно, можно: это же за 1 запрос не больше 1000. Значит, делайте несколько запросов, изменяя параметр `offset` – обычное разбиение на страницы. Имейте в виду ограничения: не более 3 запросов в секунду, и вообще не злоупотребляйте однотипными запросами.